# Why do we bother needing the mapping in route file when we use javascript routing in Play framework?

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning play framework's javascript routing by reading this article ([java version](http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=734), [scala version](http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=746)). I am questioning on the needs of these lines added in route file

```
GET     /person       controllers.Application.getAll()
DELETE  /person/:id   controllers.Application.delete(id: Long)
POST    /person       controllers.Application.create()
```

In my understanding, the javascript object appRoutes(see snippet below) has already identified which controller methods will be called after clicking each form element (delete, create, getAll), then why do we bother need the routing in place for all this to happen? What is the usage of the three lines above in route file?

```
appRoutes.controllers.Application.delete(id).ajax
appRoutes.controllers.Application.create().ajax
appRoutes.controllers.Application.getAll().ajax
```

Comment: Maybe that object uses the route files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when your use appRoutes.controllers.Application.delete(id).ajax or other javascript route, that function needs to call an url on your application.